# chartjs output data in month week and day

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm new to using chartjs, my task is to output the number of visitors to a website by month, week and day using barchart.

### login

### webapp, facebook, google

I've looked at the documentation of chartjs but it doesn't specify how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you may refer this pic .
Thanks.